# Create and download .py file by clicking HTML button

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I am writing HTML and Javascript code for a chatbot. When the chatbot returns a python program, I want a download button to appear. When I click this Download button, I want to create a .py file from this output and download it.

The following is the code that I have written.

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}

<!-- Begin page content -->
  <div class="overflow-auto">
    <br>
    <br>

    <div id="list-group" class="list-group w-auto">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex gap-3 py-3">                                                           
        <img src="https://digital-practice.ams3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/static%2Fapp%2Fimg%2Fopenai-logo.png" alt="twbs" width="32" height="32" class="rounded-circle flex-shrink-0"> 
        <div class="d-flex gap-2 w-100 justify-content-between">
          <div>
            <p class="mb-0 opacity-75">Hello. How may I help you?</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <textarea id="chat-input" class="form-control custom-control" oninput='this.style.height = "";this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + "px"'></textarea>
      <span id="gpt-button" class="input-group-asson btn btn-primary">Ask ChatGPT</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    $("gpt_button").attr("disabled", true);
  </script>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script>

    $("#gpt-button").click(function(){
    chat();
    });

    $("#chat-input").keypress(function(event){  
    if(event.which==13){
        chat();
    }
    });

    function download(data){

    const blob = new Blob([data], {type:"application/x-python-code"});

    const href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    const a = Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), {href, style:"display:none", download: "program.py"});
    document.body.appendChild(a);

    a.click();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(href);
    a.remove();
    
    }
    
    function chat(){
    var question = $("#chat-input").val();
    console.log("Test");    
    $("#chat-input").val('');


    
    let html_data = '';
    html_data += `<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex gap-3 py-3">
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/ai4eic-logo.png') }}" alt="twbs" width="32" height="32" class="rounded-circle flex-shrink-0">
        <div class="d-flex gap-2 w-100 justify-content-between">
          <div>
            <p class="mb-0 opacity-75">${question}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>`;
    $("#chat-input").val('');
    $("#list-group").append(html_data);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/chat",
        data: {'prompt': question},
        success: function (data) {

        let gpt_data = '';
        gpt_data += `

               <style> 
                       p{word-break: break-all;
                         white-space:normal;} 

                       #download-button {
                         transition: opacity 1s;
                         opacity: 0;
                        }

                       #download-button.fadeIn {
                         opacity: 1;
                         }
                </style>       


           <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex gap-3 py-3">
                    <img src="https://digital-practice.ams3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/static%2Fapp%2Fimg%2Fopenai-logo.png" alt="twbs" width="32" height="32" class="rounded-circle flex-shrink-0">  
                    <div class="d-flex gap-2 w-100 justify-content-between">
                      <div class="a">                                                           
                        <p class="mb-0 opacity-75">${data.answer}</p>    
                        <button onclick="download(${String(data.answer)})" type="button" disabled="${!(String(data.answer).includes("\`\`\`python"))}" id="download-button" class="btn btn-primary ${String(data.answer).includes("\`\`\`python") ? 'fadeIn' : ''}">Download Code</button>                
                      </div>                                                          
                    </div>                                                            
                  </a>`;
        $("#list-group").append(gpt_data);
        }
    });
    };

    </script>
 

{% endblock content %}
```

I am able to get the Download button to appear when the chatbot returns a python program. However, the code does not work after I have added the download function:

```
function download(data){

    const blob = new Blob([data], {type:"application/x-python-code"});

    const href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    const a = Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), {href, style:"display:none", download: "program.py"});
    document.body.appendChild(a);

    a.click();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(href);
    a.remove();
    
}
```

I want this to be triggered by the download button, which I have written as such

```
 <button onclick="download('${String(data.answer)}')" type="button" disabled="${!(String(data.answer).includes("\`\`\`python"))}" id="download-button" class="btn btn-primary ${String(data.answer).includes("\`\`\`python") ? 'fadeIn' : ''}">Download Code</button>
```

Comment: For one you need to quote a string `download('${data.answer}')`

Comment: Thank you, you are right! My code still isn't workin as I'd like it to though, so there must be other issues as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `disabled` attribute: the button with `onclick` will always be disabled.

Change it to not add `true/false`, but instead to not add the `disabled` attribute at all (values `true/false` don't have effect on `disabled`, if attribute is present, it means the element will be disabled, however, adding `true/false` would work if set via DOM).

Try this:

instead of:

```
disabled="${!(String(data.answer).includes("\`\`\`python"))}"
```

try (you can change the logic depending on when you want it to show/fade in):

```
${!(String(data.answer).includes("\`\`\`python")) ? 'disabled=""' : ''}
```

button part (also added quotes to function argument):

```
<button onclick="download('${String(data.answer)}')" type="button" ${!(String(data.answer).includes("\`\`\`python")) ? 'disabled=""' : ''} id="download-button" class="btn btn-primary ${String(data.answer).includes("\`\`\`python") ? 'fadeIn' : ''}">Download Code</button>
```

**EDIT**

try replacing `onclick` with jQuery:

- add id to the button

```
<button id="my-btn" ...
```

- add click handler, and pass data:

```
function download(e){

const blob = new Blob([e.data], {type:"application/x-python-code"});

const href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

const a = Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), {href, style:"display:none", download: "program.py"});
document.body.appendChild(a);

a.click();
URL.revokeObjectURL(href);
a.remove();

}
//...
$("#list-group").append(gpt_data);

$('#my-btn').click(String(data.answer), download);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still does not trigger a download upon clicking the button.

Comment: do you get any errors in dev tools. there should be one saying $ is not defined (move jquery script tag above). are there any others

Comment: it could be that the function is out of scope, so best put it within jQuery scope, i.e. replace `onclick` with jQuery's click handler

Comment: That still doesn't seem to work. I am confused by where to define the function. Currently I have it defined within the <script> tags, before my chat() function. Is this within the scope of the jQuery.ajax call within my chat function?

Comment: In addition to the "$ is not defined" error, I also get two other errors:
1. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND) (timer.js:1);
2. Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.

Although I can't seem to find any mismatched parentheses.

Comment: need to fix that: $... -> move jquery script tags before any other scripts using it, 404 ->well, the current src value is not working.. and syntax error is the most important, you can click on the line, it should open the file on the line with the error. maybe you can use your initial code, and then go step by step fixing errors and trying solutions

Comment: By inspecting the error messages in dev tools, it seems that the button click is working after all! The issue is just with the way that the string is being passed to the function, which should be easy to fix (basically if the data.answer has a quotation mark in it, it truncates the string early). Thanks for your help.

Comment: great. but, with your initial code, the button should be always disabled.., meaning, `disabled="true"` and `disabled="false"` make the element always disabled, so it should be omitted, instead of `false`